# Nginx not loading JS, CSS correctly

Tags: php, css, nginx, webserver

I am trying to reproduce https://forum.elitegaming.me/ in Nginx.  However, the server is not parsing JS and CSS files correctly.  PHP and HTML seem to load correctly.  I have proxy_pass and testcookie-nginx-module loaded.

Here is my nginx.conf:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    #default config, module disabled
    testcookie off;

    #setting cookie name
    testcookie_name BPC;

    #setting secret
    testcookie_secret FAGasffasjh3ENGN89346834tgj843g82fm832f83;

    #setting session key
    testcookie_session $remote_addr;

    #setting argument name
    testcookie_arg attempt;

    #setting maximum number of cookie setting attempts
    testcookie_max_attempts 3;

    #setting fallback url
    testcookie_fallback https://$host$request_uri;

    #configuring whitelist
    testcookie_whitelist {
        8.8.8.8/32;
        157.240.2.35/32;
    }

    #setting redirect via html code
    testcookie_redirect_via_refresh on;

    #enable encryption
    testcookie_refresh_encrypt_cookie on;

    #setting encryption key
    testcookie_refresh_encrypt_cookie_key deadbeedfeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef;

    #setting encryption iv
    testcookie_refresh_encrypt_cookie_iv deadbeedfeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef;

    #setting response template
    testcookie_refresh_template '<html>
<head>
    <meta charset= "utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv= "x-ua-compatible" content= "ie=edge">
    <meta name= "viewport" content= "width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Checking your browser..</title>
    <link href= "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel= "stylesheet">
    <link href= "/style.css" rel= "stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <header style="display:none;"></header>
    <div class="loader is-active" id="loading-content">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <main class="main">
                <div class="validation">
                    <div class="loader__items"></div>
                    <div class="lds-ellipsis">
                        <div></div>
                        <div></div>
                        <div></div>
                        <div></div>
                    </div>
                    <h2>This website is using traffic filtering to protect against malicious attacks.</h2>
                    <p>We are evaluating your browser, you will be redirected shortly.</p>
                </div>
            </main>
            <footer class="footer">
                <p>DDoS protection proudly powered by <span class="purple">Gari Web</span></p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.min.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("deadbeedfeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef"),b=toNumbers("deadbeedfeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef"),c=toNumbers("$testcookie_enc_set");document.cookie="BPC="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/";location.href="$testcookie_nexturl";</script>
</body>

</html>';

    server {
        listen 80;

        location = /aes.min.js {
            gzip  on;
            gzip_min_length 1000;
            gzip_types      text/plain;
            root /var/www/html;
        }

        location = /style.css {
            gzip  on;
            gzip_min_length 1000;
            gzip_types      text/plain;
            root /var/www/html;
        }

        location / {
            #enable module for specific location
            testcookie on;
            proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        Referer         "http://ip-of-web-space";
            proxy_pass http://ip-of-web-space; # ip of web space
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 443;

        location = /aes.min.js {
            gzip  on;
            gzip_min_length 1000;
            gzip_types      text/plain;
            root /var/www/html;
        }

        location = /style.css {
            gzip  on;
            gzip_min_length 1000;
            gzip_types      text/plain;
            root /var/www/html;
        }

        location / {
            #enable module for specific location
            testcookie on;
            proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        Referer         "http://ip-of-web-space";

            proxy_pass http://ip-of-web-space; # ip of web space
        }

    }
}
```

URL of website: https://forum.elitegaming.me
What happens: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sslWn.png)

On some browsers its loading half, but on Tor it doesnt load any css, js, etc.. files, only html, php.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason that you use Tor? Tor blocks Javascript and other files loading by default for security reasons.

You should use a 'normal' Browser like Chrome or Firefox...Then it will work probably.

Comment: its same on all browsers

Comment: Okay. Can you please show us the errors you get? (Open Chrome developer-tools by pressing F12, then go to the network-Tab and hit F5. Now you can see the http status codes for the different ressources you're trying to load.)